# Нахождение количества инверсий

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно найти количество инверсий, если Число1 больше числа2 и индекс числа1 меньше индекса числа2 то это будет являться инверсией

[image: Условие задачи]

[image: Условие задачи]

```
n = int(input())
list1 = list()
res = 0
for range1 in range(n):
    k=int(input())
    list1.append(k)
for range2 in range(len(list1)):
    for range3 in range(range2+1,len(list1)): 
        if list1[range2] > list1[range3] and range2 < range3:
            res+=1
print(res)
```

Comment: а можете дать ссылку на проверяющую систему ?

Comment: @n1tr0xs я бы с радостью но хакерранк где задания для сдачи сессии и вы не сможете зайти

Comment: `вот этот код прошёл`  Этот же код у Вас был с самого начала, и он не должен проходить при n=100000

Comment: @MBo ,а я перепутал просто у меня две одинаковых задачи только ограничения разные, извиняюсь

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

```
arr = []
res = 0
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n = int(input())
    res += sum(el > n for el in arr)
    arr.append(n)

print(res)
```

Comment: всё равно пишет что нужно быстрее

Answer (score 1):

Количество элементов 10^5 обычно подразумевает, что решение за квадрат не пройдёт, а вот O(nlogn) - устроит.

Для достижения такой сложности можно использовать сортировку слиянием. В процедуре слияния (merge) есть такой шаг, когда в результат пишется элемент из правой половины. Вот в этот момент нужно к (локальному) счётчику инверсий добавить количество ещё неиспользованных элементов левой половины.

```
invcount = 0
...
if left[i] <= right[j]:
      a[k] = left[i]
      i += 1
      k += 1    
else:
      a[k] = right[j]
      invcount += length(left) - i
      j += 1
      k += 1    
...
return invcount
```

А в рекурсивной процедуре mergesort нужно сложить количество инверсий в левой половине, количество в правой, и количество инверсий, возникающих при слиянии (то, что возвращает merge)

```
... разделение массива на две части
return mergesort(left) + mergesort(right) + merge(left, right)
```

Comment: я только не давно начал учить питон и не совсем вас понимаю, можно объяснить это чуть попроще?

Comment: @Derzh Значит, Вам нужно изучить работу алгоритма сортировки слиянием

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1:

```
A = list(int(input()) for _ in range(int(input())))
c = 0
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(A)):
        if A[i] > A[j]:
            c += 1
print(c)
```

Вариант 2:

```
A = list(int(input()) for _ in range(int(input())))
print(sum(A[i]>A[j] for i in range(len(A)) for j in range(i+1, len(A))))
```

Вариант 3:

```
A = list(int(input()) for _ in range(int(input())))
print(len([1 for i in range(len(A)) for j in range(i+1, len(A)) if A[i]>A[j]]))
```

Comment: можно написать `sum(A[i]>A[j] ...)`

Comment: @Danis спасибо за подсказку

Comment: @n1tr0xs всё равно не проходит по времени, возможно нужно без фор это решить